# EKS ALB Ingress Controller Rules

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks

Ive deployed ALB ingress in my EKS cluster which works great, already created few configuration according annotations: https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.2/guide/ingress/annotations/

SSL Redirect, etc evertything works great, even created some actions, if request comes to /path, return some action, etc

But then I have a requirement to create that kind of logic:

If Header X = 123 then return status code 200 and redirect it to somewhere, else return error code.

Shortly, I just need to implement that best practice https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/restrict-access-to-load-balancer.html#restrict-alb-route-based-on-header into ALB Ingress controller, Im using CloudFront on top of ALB and need to have Header which will be required for all request, from CloudFront I pass that request and it'll work but nobody else should access to the ALB endpoint directly without Header and its propper/correct value

Ive already tried something like this:

```
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.rule-path7: >
      {"type":"fixed-response","fixedResponseConfig":{"contentType":"text/plain","statusCode":"200","messageBody":"multiple conditions applies"}}
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/conditions.rule-path7: >
      [{"field":"http-header","httpHeaderConfig":{"httpHeaderName": "HeaderName", "values":["HeaderValue"]}},{"field":"query-string","queryStringConfig":{"values":[{"key":"paramA","value":"valueA"}]}},{"field":"query-string","queryStringConfig":{"values":[{"key":"paramB","value":"valueB"}]}}]
spec:
```

It makes sense if I like return status code 200 if Header is correct, but how return error code if header doesnt exist, thats a question....